# UseEffect not filling all states

Tags: arrays, reactjs, function, state, use-effect

SO this is my code, i'm trying to filter my offers by there users , i have called all my offers and all my user and there states are full but when i try to filter offers by there users the state stay empty but when i hit spacebar on my keyboard the state get full like it's the spacebar is triggering useEffect to fill the state

```
const [offer, setOffer] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const[useroffers,setUseroffer]=useState([]);


  const isOffer = async () => {
    const oflg = await GetAllOff();
    setOffer(oflg);
  };


  const isLoggedIn = async () => {
    const userLg = await CurrentUser();
    setUser(userLg.data.user);
  };

  const isUseroffer = async()=>{
   setUseroffer(offer.filter((el)=>el.createdbyId === user._id));
  };
 
 
  useEffect( () => {
    isOffer();
    isLoggedIn();
    isUseroffer();
  }, []);
  console.log(offer);
  console.log(user)
  console.log(useroffers);
```

So useEffect is filling the offers and user States but not filling the useroffers state intil i click on the spacebar

Comment: new state values won't be available until the render cycle after they are set, so trying to set a state that depends on another state value will not necesarily have access to the relevant value. Better to have a second `useEffect` with a dependendency on `user` so that when `user` changes the offers are filtered. `useEffect(() => {isUseroffer()}, [user]);`

Comment: this has created me an infinite loop

Comment: There's no reason you should be. Here's a quick [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/user-array-filter-example-bqh9ib?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I see that most of your questions have answers that solve your problem, but that you have not accepted any answers. This limits the usefulness of the answers as they can't be linked as duplicates etc. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and accept the answers that addressed your issues in each of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

`useroffers` is dependent on both `user` and `offer` but you are trying to set it in the same render cycle as those two. Updated state values aren't available until the render cycle after they are set, so `setUseroffers` doesn't have access to the values it needs to update properly. To solve this you can declare a second `useEffect` which is dependent on `user` and `offer` so that as those values update so does your filtered array.

```
  const [offer, setOffer] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [useroffers, setUseroffer] = useState([]);

  const isOffer = async () => {
    const oflg = await GetAllOff();
    setOffer(oflg);
  };

  const isLoggedIn = async () => {
    const userLg = await CurrentUser();
    setUser(userLg.data.user);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    isOffer();
    isLoggedIn();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUseroffer(offer.filter((el) => el.createdbyId === user._id));
  }, [user, offer]);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/user-array-filter-example-bqh9ib?file=/src/App.js)

---

Alternatively you can do it all in a single `useEffect` by awaiting the `offer` and `user` values and using them directly to set all three states once they are available. (This will result in only a single rerender rather than the possible four in the previous example)

```
  const [offer, setOffer] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [useroffers, setUseroffer] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const login = async () => {
      const userLg = await CurrentUser();
      const ofLg = await GetAllOff();

      setUser(userLg.data.user);
      setOffer(ofLg);
      setUseroffer(
        ofLg.filter((el) => el.createdbyId === userLg.data.user._id)
      );
    };

    login();
  }, []);
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/user-array-filter-example-all-in-one-uimuqt)